# How to run two processes as though they were one in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, process, scripting

I've got two commands foo and bar.

foo runs for a long time without stdin or stdout/stderr activity. bar is a client of foo and runs with stdout/stderr but no stdin activity.

I'd like to run them from one shell, being able to kill both with ctrl-c, and to see the output from bar as it occurs.

i.e. something like this sequence

foo &
bar
kill -9

but without having to manually do the kill - instead it just happens on ctrl-c

is there a way of scripting this?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `kill -9`.

You want to trap on `EXIT`, not on `INT`.

```
trap 'kill $fooPid $barPid' EXIT
foo & fooPid=$!
bar & barPid=$!
wait
```

This solution will always make sure to terminate `foo` and `bar`, whatever the reason for it exiting (excluding it being `SIGKILL`'ed).

If you want to avoid keeping PIDs (which has some race condition issues) you can do this instead:

```
trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' EXIT
foo &
bar &
wait
```

That's a better (and cleaner!) solution if your script has no other jobs.

**Ps**:
These solutions mean `foo` and `bar` can write to your terminal (your script's `stdout`), but neither can read from `stdin`.  If you need either `foo` or `bar` to read from stdin, the solution becomes a *bit* more complex.

Comment: Agree with everything you say except the kill -9. I've seen that touted before but it's fine if you understand what the processes do. As long as they have no resources that outlive the process, -9 is fine, and avoids the (possibly) messy staged kills (kill ,then kill -9 later if they refuse to die).

Comment: @Pax: If you know what the process does and it doesn't need any cleanup then SIGTERM is 100% identical to SIGKILL, so you might as well send SIGTERM.  And messy staged kills should indeed be avoided at all costs; by sending only SIGTERM and growing patience :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a bash script to run the programs and use `trap` to capture the CTRL-C. Then, in the function called by trap, just kill off the programs.

It's been a while since I did this but I think the following illustrates it.

```
#!/bin/bash
xx() {
    kill -9 $pid1
    kill -9 $pid2
    echo bye
}
trap 'xx' SIGINT
sleep 1000 &
pid1=$!
sleep 2000 &
pid2=$!
sleep 3600
```

Just run this script and CTRL-C it, you'll find that it kills off the two sleep processes.